# get the value of a hiera data from a puppet node without executing the full manifest

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, hiera

I am very new to Puppet and I have spent quite some time to figure the things which I am asking below but was not able to get any specific answers.

Basically I have some puppet modules in my local git repo. From the manifest files I can see that they are using variables from Hiera. However I just want to know the value of some of the Hiera variables so that I can test some very specific things in some other place by hardcoding the properties.

So basically what I need is just to call some command line function or similar thing from a node to find out what is the value of the Hiera variable as set on the master. I do not have access to puppet master and so can't just login and check the values.

Can you please help in case we have something like this in Puppet.

Regards,
Pulkit

Comment: Can you inject Puppet code on the master via git in lieu of logging in directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All for helping me.

As far as I was able to research I think I go with Felix that it is not possible to know what hiera value is set on master.
However, I just came to know that we are maintaining a git repo which contains all the hiera files which are then applied to puppet master.

I think this can be a better approach to maintain hiera files in a git repo so that one can find what is set on master without actually logging into the puppet master.

Please correct me if it feels wrong.